How to React lazy load components which are default exports but are imported from a common file for exports only
I am maintaining a separate file "exporter.js" which imports all the default export components and then exports from there to keep import statements clean.


export { default as Posts } from './Posts/Posts';
export { default as Form } from './Form/Form';
export { default as Home } from './Home';
export { default as Footer} from "./Footer/Footer";
export { default as Header} from "./Header/Header";
export { default as AllPosts} from "./AllPosts/AllPosts";
export { default as LoginAndRegister} from "./LoginAndRegister/LoginAndRegister";



and then I'm importing components like this in the main.js file


import './index.css'
import React from 'react'
import store from './app/store.js'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import Layout from './components/Layout.jsx'
import { Toaster } from './components/ui/toaster.jsx'
import { fetchMemoryPosts } from './features/postsSlice.js';
import { Route, RouterProvider, createBrowserRouter, createRoutesFromElements } from 'react-router-dom';

//********************* importing components*****************************
import { Home, LoginAndRegister, AllPosts } from './components/exporter.js'
//***********************************************************************


const router = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
      <Route path='' element={<AllPosts />}/>
      <Route path='/register-login' element={<LoginAndRegister />} />
      <Route path='/my-memories' element={<Home />} />
    </Route>
  )
)

store.dispatch(fetchMemoryPosts());

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
      <Toaster />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
)



How do I apply React lazy loading to these components "import { Home, LoginAndRegister, AllPosts } from './components/exporter.js'"?

This is not supported directly.
Are you looking for this workaround:
const { Home, LoginAndRegister, AllPosts } = lazy(() =>
  import('./components/exporter.js').then(module => ({
    Home: module.Home,
    LoginAndRegister: module.LoginAndRegister,
    AllPosts: module.AllPosts,
  })),
);


Should I cover the  also is the Suspense?

Yes. <Suspense> is needed for dynamic components. Add it at a level such that all your dynamic loading components are inside the tree. FWIW, we use it around <Provider> in my project
